# Rerunning query in the same connection takes significantly longer

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I am having a weird issue when a running a query that joins some semi-large tables (one table is about 2 million rows and the other about 21 million) together.  What happens is the query does not run within the same time frame consistently.  If I run the query on a new connection in SSMS it takes about 45 seconds to complete.  After it completes if I hit the execute button again it takes almost 4 minutes to complete.  If I then open a new query (connection) and execute the query it takes about 45 seconds again.  These queries are being run from the server and I can consistently reproduce this.

Any help on what is going on and how to fix is helpful.

Comment: suggest you to look into the difference between execution plans for - when the query runs fast and when it runs slow. Are stats and indexes up-to-date ?

Comment: Have you looked at execution plans for the "fast" and "slow" versions?  Are they exactly the same?  If not, therein lieth your answer.  Check this answer for some real gold:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60181/10832

Comment: @Kin Yes the indexes and stats are up to date.I will compare the query plans.  Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that many rows, moving the results from the server to the client will be a significant part of the elapsed time.  Eliminate variablity in that part by wrapping your query in some way such as:

```
select
    count(*)
from (
    {your query here}
) as xx
```

This way the network transfer will be a minimal part of the elapsed time and you can eliminate it from your enquiries.